The first time opening a component through Lazy in Nuxt is very long
Using Nuxt layouts
in the default layout I connect modals components with Lazy
And when I try to open some modal, its first opening takes a very long time. Subsequent openings happen quickly.
When the page is reloaded, the problem persists.
I asked chatGPT, he suggested wrapping all lazy modals in <keep-alive>. but this did not solve the problem
<template>
      <LazyModalsProduct v-if="catalogStore.isShowProductModal" />
      <LazyModalsChooseDiscount v-if="isShowChooseDiscountModal" />
      <LazyModalsCart v-if="isShowCartModal" />

      <LazyModalsPopup
      v-if="isShowPopupModal"
      />

      <LazyModalsHeaderInfoMenu
      v-if="isShowMobileMenu"
      />

      <LazyModalsFilters
        v-if="isShowFiltersModal"
      />

      <LazyModalsOrder
        v-if="isShowOrderModal"
      />
</template>

bool vars I compute in script
<script setup>
const isShowAuthModal = computed(() => commonStore.isShowAuthModal);
const isShowSettingsModal = computed(() => commonStore.isShowSettingsModal);
const isShowAcceptCityModal = computed(() => commonStore.isShowAcceptCityModal);
const isShowDeliveryTypeModal = computed(() => commonStore.isShowDeliveryTypeModal);
const isShowPopupModal = computed(() => commonStore.isShowPopupModal);

</script>

tried to load some (1-2) modals withOut using "Lazy", but it doesn't solve the problem.
also tried <keep-alive>, but no result.
I expect the same time of opening these modals.

Using lazy-loading for your components will not automatically solve any of those issues. Keep-alive will not help either on the initial render (do not waste time with AI for those issues). By using Lazy, you're actually delaying the loading of the whole component. If you remove all the Lazys, I guess that you have an initial slow render but then, everything's better, right? Hence I recommend not Lazying everything. You could also start loading things on over, so that the loading happens before the click but so far, Lazying everything is not the way to go all the time everywhere.

I found solution, it seems to work.
<LazyModalsCategories v-if="isShowCategoriesModal || isModalOpened" />

<LazyModalsAuth v-if="isShowAuthModal || isModalOpened" />

<LazyModalsSettings v-if="isShowSettingsModal || isModalOpened" />

For every my lazy-modal component I added one more condition to "v-if" block.
All needed modals I mathed with this "isModalOpened" variable.
const isModalOpened = ref(false);

And after this, in onMounted I switch it
onMounted(async () => {
  // some my code

  isModalOpened.value = true;

  nextTick(() => {
    isModalOpened.value = false;
  })
});

We won't see any changes on the page, we won't see this modal "tick-opening", but now first time modal (hand) opening should be momental
